# E-Commerce Product page HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, e-commerce

Is it necessary to make a html file in a folder for every single product page(for each product) or can i do this with JS. If got 1000 products that would be a lot of files.

If you know some pages where this Problem is shown(thought), pls send me the link.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some e-commerces frameworks like Woocommerce, Magento or Prestashop.

you can also make your code with some server-side langague like Node.JS or PHP, with these languages is just make a template of product page and add variables with product data.

Tutorials:

[Node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fy9SdZLBTOo)

[PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE-CZ379_eg)

Frameworks:

[Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/)

[Magento](https://magento.com/)

[PrestaShop](https://www.prestashop.com/en)